# Upload image for profile user on django framwork

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.2

this is my repository github:https://github.com/Andrygaby/mySite_projecte/tree/master/fullProject/user

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginner with django and I want to upload an image for my user profile,and then there are nothing displayed on the page where I pretend to put the image of the user.I pretend to put on profile_user.html and edit_profile.html,